# "Network error trying to communicate with the server (0)." "Error de red tratanto de comunicarse con el servidor (0)."

Tags: genexus

I have a KB in GX Evo 3 (generating with JAVA) and in that KB there is a table that is modified from two different transactions

The first transaction "creates" the record in the database of the type

```
* id
Field1
field2
Field3 = '.'
```

and the other transaction enters in UPD mode and modifies a record field

*Id
Field1 (with a NoAccept rule)
Field3 = HERE THE DATA TO BE MODIFIED IS LOADED

Before (in some cases) an error appeared:

> "Network error trying to communicate with the server (0)."

Now every time an entry is made in the second form, the same error appears. Has it happened to anyone? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,the webmaster hided my previous answers because I wrote in spanish...
I already had your problem and I solved succesfully:
You have some attribute that is changed when the program runs (i.e. by a gx rule or db default etc). Clean the Tomcat logs (7 or newer) run the program and look into the catalina.out for lines like  TransactionXX:[SendSecurityCheck value for]AttributeYY:valueZZ and a few lines below will be some line with TransactionXX:[SecurityCheckFailed value for]AtributeYY:valueOTRO being TransactionXX your GX TRN, AttributeYY some attr of the TRN that was changed from "valueZZ" to "valueOTRO" while running (most cases into the Event Start).
Te GX doc I found is https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34108,Error+403
I hope this explanation (3rd attempt) is valid.
Yours
JC